# User Registration Form Redirect not working Craft 2.5

Tags: redirect, registration, devmode

I'm using the following code but the redirect is not working. After the user registers it takes them back to the home page and not to `volunteer/identity`. I put a message on the homepage to display if the user is logged in and it appears that they are logged it at that point. This used to work before 2.5 on a different site that I haven't upgraded to 2.5. But now on this new install of 2.5 I can't get it to work.

Has anyone else experienced the same issues?

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}

<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="volunteer/identity">

    {% macro errorList(errors) %}
        {% if errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}

    {% from _self import errorList %}

    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" {% if account is defined %} value="{{ account.firstName }}"{% endif %}>

    {% if entry is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('firstName')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName" required {% if account is defined %} value="{{ account.lastName }}{% endif %}">

    {% if entry is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('lastName')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email"
        {% if account is defined %} value="{{ account.email }}"{% endif %}>

    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('email')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password">

    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <button type="submit" class="button">Save and continue</button>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

My config file looks like this:

```
return array(
    'devMode' => true,
    'useEmailAsUsername' => true,
    'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true,
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    'setPasswordPath' => array(
        'en' => 'account/setpassword'
    ),
);
```

Comment: So, if it's redirecting to the homepage and they are logged in, you're saying that it also skips the whole activation/email verification process altogether, correct? Anything in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` ?

Comment: Yes, I've turned off Verify email addresses in `admin/settings/users/settings` so it doesn't verify anything. I'll check the logs now.

Comment: @ChaseGiunta I checked the logs for `redirect` and I found this

    $_POST=array (
      'action' => 'users/saveUser'
      'redirect' => 'volunteer/identity'
      'firstName' => 'qwetr'
      'lastName' => 'erty'
      'email' => 'fdgh@me.com'
      'password' => REDACTED
    )

So it looks like it is getting the correct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Craft 2.6, if a hidden `redirect` input is set, Craft will now follow it first and fallback to the [activateAccountSuccessPath](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#activateAccountSuccessPath) if it's not available.

Comment: Thanks Brad! When is 2.6 coming out? soonish? Looks like Craft is only at 2.5.2757. Is there something I can do to patch it at the moment?

Comment: No ETA on 2.6, but hit up support@craftcms.com for the patched file if you want it. Just keep in mind that an auto-update could overwrite it at anytime, though.

Comment: That's true. Ok, I'll send for a patched file. Thanks.

Comment: The patched file fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for (it should be honoring your redirect) but if that's the only form being used for registrations, you could set `'activateAccountSuccessPath' => 'volunteer/identity'` in your config file.

Comment: Yes, that's true. It should be honoring the redirect. I can try that for now but I'd rather not hard code this. This should work for now. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue as OP, and since we work with e-mail address verification, this workaround isn't suitable. It should honor the right settings, indeed.

Comment: @tom: I emailed support@craftcms.com and they sent me a patched file that fixed the issue for now.

Comment: @cavellblood Thank you for this heads-up. Very helpful. I will mail them too.